# Possible plot-related questions for shows/series that are ongoing. Should be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Based on [this comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/767/why-gajeel-start-getting-motion-sickness#comment976_767), where **Gorchestopher H** says:

> I don't believe we have the answer to this yet. It appears that it
>   will be a plot point later on, as his new-found motion sickness has
>   something to do with his personal growth in the dragonslayer realm.

Should [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/767/why-gajeel-start-getting-motion-sickness) be closed until this mystery is revealed, or edited in a way to be more `answerable` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, the OP cannot *know* that there is no answer yet (unless he's doing it on purpose). So we can't, nor should we punish him by downvoting or closing his question.

As for "temporarily closing the question".

1. Not practical. Forget about it.
2. Why? Since the question *is* going to be answerable one way or another (Either the detail is revealed later in the series, and then we can answer it, or it isn't revealed at all, and the series ends, in which case the correct answer is

   > It wasn't revealed.

   As small as that is, it *is* an answer.

For those reasons, I don't see a reason to close the question, and prevent it from being answered in the future (Again, no one is going to remember to open them up).

Comment: Basically, any question (that can't be assured to be on purpose.) that ask about something that doesn't exist at the moment, should be treated like this?

Comment: @MichelAyres: If it doesn't exist *at this moment*, then yes. It should be kept open. Maybe even answer a CW about how it wasn't revealed yet. If the show ended, and the question remains unanswerable, it can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question:

> This "sickness" has anything to do with Pantherlily becoming his "cat" ?

Is more answerable than the general "why". But even so, it could still just be speculation.

This problem will come up when possible plot-related questions pop up for shows/series that are ongoing. Unless the OP simply missed something that has happened, the answer is usually "nobody knows (yet)". Personally, I don't see a problem with leaving these questions open until an answer is revealed. It would be easier than closing the question and waiting for it to be re-opened, or asking a duplicate question. If there isn't an answer yet, nobody should give an answer.

Comment: I took part of your text and changed the title =)

Comment: "If there isn't an answer yet, nobody should give an answer." imo you should bold this. I definitely agree that "nobody knows" shouldn't be an answer for ongoing series. If the series ended and there really is no answer, that's fine. But don't do it for ongoing stuff.