# Please reopen this question closed as POB

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, specific-question

The question [How is Armament Haki obtained or learned?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21592/99) is closed as primarily opinion based, because of an incorrect assumption that primarily opinion based means "we don't know the answer *yet*".

Based on [this meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/99), questions whose answers are not yet revealed should be left open. Hence, I request that the question be reopened.

As I mention in the comments, there is a realistic chance of the answer being revealed in the future. A flashback showing Luffy's training at Rusukaina is one such possibility.

Note: In case anyone is wondering why I voted to close and then mention here that the reason is incorrect, that's because of the SE limitation of not being able to cast a reopen vote until the question is closed.

Comment: This has been done.